# How to implement side bar table of contents as per Angular Docs website

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm looking to implement a right side table of contents as per any page on the Angular Docs website [Example Here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0). The app itself is Angular 6 with twitter bootstrap.  I've had a look at the Angular/Angular Material guide but can't see any docs for it. Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: are you using ngBootstrap or regular bootstrap?

Comment: Both I think.  I have this in my main.scss `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` and also have access to the ngb components.

Comment: you should only use ngBootstrap. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home It's not good practice to be using both and it's better practice to use ngBootstrap only since it doesn't' have any dependencies on jQuery